# Extracting subjective phrases from sentences

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a set of sentences from which I want to extract all the subjective phrases.

For eg., from **I am pleased to learn that the president has been reelected.**, I want to extract **am pleased**. What is the way to do that?

**Edit:** So each sentence can be divided into subjective and objective phrases. For example in the sentence:

```
Barack Obama is the President of the USA but I don't think he's doing a good job.
```

Here, the first part, `Barack Obama is the President of the USA` is the objective part of the phrase as it states the fact but `I don't think he's doing a good job` is the subjective part of the phrase which gives the sentiment. I want to extract all such subjective phrases from a bunch of sentences. What I have access to is a bunch of documents which have sentences with corresponding documents already containing the subjective phrases present in these documents. I need to find a method which I can use to understand how these subjective phrases are constructed so that I can extract subjective phrases from a new set of sentences/documents. If anyone is aware of some papers or any other sources dealing with this, it would be of great help.

Comment: If you have a list of subjective words, you just do a search with fgrep. Or did you have something more complex in mind?

Comment: I have some lines and the subjective phrases present in each one of them. I have to find the subjective phrases in a new set of sentences. I just wanted to know if there are a set of standard rules to do that.

Comment: No. "Subjective phrase" is not a standard linguistic term; so it will depend on whatever software or theory you are using, which won't be standard.

Comment: @Expressions_Galore: Do you mean *subjective* in the regular sense "based on or influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions." Or in the grammar/linguistics sense "relating to or denoting a case of nouns and pronouns used for the subject of a sentence."?

Comment: By subjectivity, I mean what's mentioned in these slides: http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5340/slides/sentiment.4pp.pdf

Comment: The slides mention a few tools. Are they not enough? Perhaps you could go through [this tutorial on Sentiment Analysis](http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/), in particular, [the chapter on lexicons](http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/lexicons.html)